# How can I generate refresh token in asp.net?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, azure-active-directory, access-token, refresh-token

I'm able to get access token from client side using google file picker. But the access token expires after 3600 seconds. I scratched my head to get the refresh token but unable to do it on C# ASP.NET. Can somebody help with the C# code to understand and retrieve the refresh token ? It will be very helpful. Thank You.

I tried using *GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync*, it works in my local machine but doesn't work on the production IIS server. I also tried *GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow* but unable to go further in it and I don't know how to use it.

```
IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleDriveClientID"],
                        ClientSecret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleDriveClientSecret"]
                    },
                    Scopes = Scopes,
                    DataStore = null
                });
```

I tried this but I don't know how to move forward after this.

Comment: Can you include your definition for `Scopes`?

Comment: public static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };

Comment: @Vivek Take a look if it is resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to generate refresh token from your C# code sample.

You could try following code snippet:

**Refresh Token Example:**

```cs
public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
    {
        private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "yourClientId",
                        ClientSecret = "yourClientSecret"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
                });

        public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
        {
            // In this sample we use the session to store the user identifiers.
            // That's not the best practice, because you should have a logic to identify
            // a user. You might want to use "OpenID Connect".
            // You can read more about the protocol in the following link:
            // https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.
            var user = controller.Session["user"];
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = Guid.NewGuid();
                controller.Session["user"] = user;
            }
            return user.ToString();

        }

        public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
        {
            get { return flow; }
        }
    }
```

**Note:** If you have any more query on how you get [`ClientId`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_client_secrets), [`ClientSecret`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_client_secrets) and [`Scope`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_client_secrets), please refer to this [MVC Example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth).

Comment: Thanks. But I'm using ASP.NET so I think I've to modify this code accordingly since it's written for MVC.

Comment: No Problem functionality is same. There is no difference for asp.net web forms and MVC